# My cell phone (Android) in the emulator (uiautomator)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ui-automation

I'm trying to connect my phone to the emulator (uiautomator - Android Studio), but to no avail.

My phone is displayed on "adb devices", but when I connect to display it on my emulator, nothing happens (error also not displayed).

Can anybody help me?
Android Version: 9.0 (Pie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the SDK corresponding to Android 9. You can do it in Android studio by setting the target SDK to 28 (android 9) and installing the missing SDK prompted by Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check if you have USB debugging on in developer settings on your phone.

Comment: Hi @wutamidoin.
Yes it is! What can it be?!
My phone is the LG G8s ThinQ.
I have tried everything .. =//